# jQuery UI Accordion in dyn. filled div ( div in div)

Tags: jquery, html, load, accordion

I'm new in programming with jQuery.

I tried to load new content in a div called "container". The new content has a div included, which should be shown as jQuery UI Accordion.

The content change works fine, but the accordion isn't shown. How can i apply the Accordion on the loaded div?

Code
(inspired by: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/):

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{   
        $('#navlist li a').click(function()
        {                             
            var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#container').hide('fast',loadContent);
            $('#load').remove();
            $('#page').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
            $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
            function loadContent()
            {
                $('#container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
            }
            function showNewContent()
            {
                $('#container').show('normal',hideLoader());
            }
            function hideLoader()
            {
                $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
            }       
            return false;
        });


        $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only applying the `accordion` on `$(document).ready`.

You need to call `accordion()` after you load your new content:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
        $('#navlist li a').click(function()
        {                             
            var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#container').hide('fast',loadContent);
            $('#load').remove();
            $('#page').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
            $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
            function loadContent()
            {
                $('#container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
            }
            function showNewContent()
            {   
                // ADD THIS:
                $('#container #accordion').accordion();
                $('#container').show('normal',hideLoader());
            }
            function hideLoader()
            {
                $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
            }       
            return false;
        });


        $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```